# what is big object .usages and limits?

Tags: big-object

What is big object. Usages and limits and diffidence between object vs big object,please anybody help on this.

Comment: Please share what do you know already as if you simply search it you will find many links.

Comment: can create up to 100 big objects per org. The limits for big object fields are similar to the limits on custom objects and depend on your org’s license type. 
They have been built to provide consistent performance whether there is 1 million records, 100 million, or even 1 billion records. This scale is what gives big objects their power and what defines the features that are provided.
Storage Limit of Big Objects should not change Governor Limits.

Comment: Please add these details to your question...and specify what limits exactly you are looking for.

Comment: big object Limits and how to using visuforce page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding limitations of big objects:

- You can create a unique index but can not modify it later
- 5 fields allowed in the index and the sum of text fields should be at maximum 50.
- Only lookups, Text (long), Integer and DateTime are allowed as fields.
- DMLs are not transactional
- You can not use them inside a trigger. Only with future methods/queueables

Comment: Please also note: If a big object is deployed and released in managed namespace, it can not be deleted. The only possible way (until now) is to open a ticket and they will revert all releases into the one that it was first introduced. This means that if you need to modify its index, then this object becomes obsolete. Since modifying or deleting indexes is not allowed either.